# How to initialise a git repository with libgit2

Tags: c++, windows, libgit2

On a Windows XP, 32-bit machine I've cloned the libgit2 repository using

```
git clone git://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git trunk
```

Then I configured from trunk_build_debug for mingw using:

```
cmake ../trunk -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-g
```

and build-ed it with

```
make
```

With this newly build library I'm trying to create a new repository. So I'm using

```
    error_code = git_repository_init( &repo, path, 0 );
    if ( error_code != 0 )
    {
        const git_error * error = giterr_last();
       /* the text representation:
        ( error == NULL || error->message == NULL ? 
        "(no description)" : 
        error->message )
        */
    }
```

On first attempt this fails with the error message:

> Git error -1: The global file '.config/git/config' doesn't exist:  The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

The .git directory is created and I can use `git status` to query it. Also, I have git installed in Program Files/git and it works just fine. The file that is mentioned does not exist in user directory, that is true. I'm not happy because I can't check the returned error code (the error may be "real").

So I've created an empty file in D:\Documents and Settings\User Name.config\git\config
The .git directory is again created but I get the same -1 error code. This time giterr_last() returns NULL.

Tracing the code in debugger seems to indicate that the library is not happy with my empty file.

However, I think this indicates that I'm doing something wrong. Is there an initialization method? Do I need to create the file and use the git_config_ functions to point the library to it?

BTW, is this the wrong place to ask this? Is there a dedicated forum where I should ask this question?

Thanks

---

Here is the back trace where the call fails: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eJA7manB) 
It seems that the configure file inside .git directory can't be parsed (not shown in in trace is the 'config_parse()' that fails).

---

I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/1400) in libgit2.

Answer (score 4):

To create a new repository, one should rather rely on `git_repository_init()`. For more information, you can peek at the **[header](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/repository.h#L139-157)** and the **[tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/tests-clar/repo/init.c)**.

`git_repository_open()` should rather be used when the repository already exists.

> Is there a dedicated forum where I should ask this question?

It's ok to ask programming related question on StackOverflow. Beside this, some libgit2 developers hang out in the #libgit2 channel on irc.freenode.net. However, when you encounter bugs, it's recommended to submit them to the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues)**.

### Update

- There had been some issues in the past with the way the configuration files are being probbed on Windows. Along with some attempts to fix them. See this **[issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/952)** for some background about this.
- Beside the complexity of the probbing, some users may want to explictly provide alternate locations for their files. This **[pull request](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1291)** works this angle.

Considering what you discovered while debugging the libgit2, maybe now would be a good time to open a bug in the issue tracker. Beware that two issues may be at play: the probbing one and and the empty config issue.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I use 'git_repository_init()' in my code; it was an copy-paste mistake on posting the question. The issues remain.

Comment: I just checked Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit and an XP running inside VirtualBox (without a previous git installation) and the problem never occurred. I shall check on the original machine again tomorrow and may file a bug report.